# C: List sort code not working

Tags: c, list, sorting, bubble-sort

I cannot figure out why my code to sort the elements of a list does not work, it sort the first 5 element of the list and then just stop. I know it may be a stupid problem but I checked the loop a lot of time and can't understand why it reach the exit before the end of the list.

```
typedef enum { NOTORD=0, TIME=1, POSITION=2  } ord_t;


typedef struct elem {
  double position;
  double time;
  flag_t flag;
  struct elem * next;
} elem_t;

typedef struct {
  elem_t * head;
  int nelem; 
  ord_t ord; 
} lista_t;


void set_ordinata_time (lista_t * l) 
{
if (l->ord!=TIME) {
    elem_t * aux, *corr, *succ;
    int scambio;
    corr=l->head;
    succ=l->head->next;
    aux=malloc(sizeof(elem_t));
    scambio=1;
    while(scambio==1)
    {
        corr=l->head;
        succ=l->head->next;
        scambio=0;
        while(succ != NULL)
        {
            if (corr->time > succ->time)
            {
                aux=corr;
                aux->next=succ->next;
                corr=succ;
                succ=aux;
                corr->next=succ;
                scambio=1;
            }
            corr=succ; succ=succ->next;
        }
    }
    l->ord=TIME;
}

}
```

Comment: In it's present form this is a "why isn't this code working" type question, which should be closed as offtopic. Did you try running the code in a debugger to see why it stops?

Answer (score 0):

When you are swapping, if `corr` is `l->head` then you need to reset `l->head` to `succ`. If you don't, then the next time through the loop, the sort will start from wherever `l->head` ended up after the first pass.

Also, you will be losing (and leaking) part of the list.

EDIT: More from comments

It applies generally to `corr`'s previous element (it needs to be reset to `succ` when swapping)

Comment: sorry I can't understand that. Corr is l->head at the beginning of the inner loop, then it change to the next element of the list and so on.. After that I reset corr=l->head at the beginning of every while(scambio==1) loop. What am I missing?

Comment: I understood what you were saying and I added "if (corr==l->head) l->head=succ;" at the beginning of the inner loop but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's more than that -- When you swap corr and succ, the element that used to point to corr needs to have its next set to succ.  I pointed out the l->head case, but it applies generally to corr's previous element (it needs to be reset to succ when swapping)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to allocate an instance of elem_t. When swapping elements, there's an issue if one of the elements is the first one in the list, or if the elements are adjacent elements. Using pointers to pointer to element can reduce the number of if statements. A pointer to pointer could be the address of head or the address of a nodes next pointer.

To implement a swap, first swap whatever points to the two nodes (could be head or a node next pointer), then swap the two nodes next pointers. This will take care of the adjacent versus not adjacent node issue.